# Error inserting a record in SQLite DB

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert

```
public class DBCreation extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

Context context;
public DBCreation(Context context)
{
    super(context, "LBRDatabase", null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) throws SQLException 
{
        db.execSQL("create table Reminders(id integer primary key autoincrement,description text,address text not null,latitude double not null,longitude double not null,radius text,reminderdate text,remindertime text);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    try
    {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists Reminders ");
        onCreate(db);
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

}
```

What is the problem with this code?
It is giving me the following error?

```
06-18 08:54:30.843: E/Database(6452): Error inserting Reminders
06-18 08:54:30.843: E/Database(6452): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Reminders: , while compiling: INSERT INTO Reminders(radius, longitude, latitude, reminderdate, address, description, remindertime) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

The table is getting created.The order of insertion is also not proper.It is first taking radius then longitude, then longitude which is not the order in which i created the table.

```
public class DBOperations
{
Context context;
SQLiteDatabase db;
DBCreation createdb;

public DBOperations(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    createdb = new DBCreation(context);
}

public DBCreation OpenDB() throws SQLException
{
    db = createdb.getWritableDatabase();
    return createdb;
}

public void CloseDB()
{
    db.close();
}

public long addReminder(String description,String address,double latitude,double longitude,String radius,String date,String time)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("description", description);
    cv.put("address", address);
    cv.put("latitude", latitude);
    cv.put("longitude", longitude);
    cv.put("radius", radius);
    cv.put("reminderdate", date);
    cv.put("remindertime", time);

    return db.insert("Reminders", null, cv);
}

public long deleteReminder(int id)
{
    return db.delete("Reminders", "_ID="+id, null);
}

public long updateReminder(int id,String desc,String addr,double lat,double lon,int radius,String date,String time)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("description", desc);
    cv.put("address", addr);
    cv.put("latitude", lat);
    cv.put("longitude", lon);
    cv.put("radius", radius);
    cv.put("reminderdate", date);
    cv.put("remindertime", time);
    return db.update("Reminders", cv, "_ID="+id, null);
}

public Cursor showReminders()
{
    Cursor c = db.query("Reminders", null, null , null, null, null, null);
    if(c!=null)
    {
        return c;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Reminders:` Are you sure the table is created?

Comment: I have a Toast with a message if there is an error creating the table and as it is not displaying the toast so i guess yes the table is created.If there is a better way to find out please tell me?

Answer (score 1):

Your CREATE TABLE syntax is incorrect. From the [fine manual](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html):

> **The AUTOINCREMENT Keyword**
>
> If a column has the type `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` then a slightly different `ROWID` selection algorithm is used.

Note that it says **AUTOINCREMENT**, not **AUTO_INCREMENT**. So your `Reminders` table really isn't being created and the INSERT is rightfully complaining.

Comment: What makes you think your `onCreate` is getting called at all?

Comment: I have edited the question.You can see the entire class now.Please tell me if i am doing something wrong here?

Comment: Yes i think onCreate() method is not getting called.But do you know what might be the possible reason?

Comment: Sorry, I'm more of a database guy than an Android guy but I'm certain that your `onCreate` is not being called. Are you calling `OpenDB` anywhere? Presumably that would trigger the `onCreate` call, right?

Comment: yes OpenDB calls the onCreate method,but i dont know whats wrong because i am calling OpenDB and nothing is happening.

Comment: Is your [`getWritableDatabase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase()) call calling `onOpen` perhaps? Maybe it thinks `onCreate` has already been called for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think your d`atabase is not created`

You have to create database proper way with format
[here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) you can findout `example`.

If you have any query then put comment.

Comment: i think the onCreate() method is not getting called

Comment: you have to create your database object this way. DBCreation db = new DBCreation(mContext);

Answer (score 0):

when creating the table, for the primary key "_id", it is suppose to be "AUTOINCREMENT" without the underscore in between. Probably you can try that?

Comment: even after making it autoincrement the error is still the same

Answer (score 0):

In your add reminder method, the place where u are putting values into cv, have you tried putting a dummy value for the field _id? I understand that you have set the column to autoincrement but it is also the primary key which cannot be null. 
Putting a dummy value for that column might help.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, but my query structure was incorrect. Here the correct sample of a query that I made. Hope this help ya :)

```
   CREATE TABLE "Configuration" (
"_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
"id_Users" INTEGER, 
"Key" VARCHAR(255), 
"Value" VARCHAR(255)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

first create table then open table in append or open to write mode and then insert data

Answer (score 0):

for newbee.... create simple databaseHelper class like below(Why use two different class & create confusion):

```
public class DBController  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  private static final String LOGCAT = null;

  public DBController(Context applicationcontext) {
    super(applicationcontext, "androidsqlite.db", null, 1);
    Log.d(LOGCAT,"Created");
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    String query;
    query = "CREATE TABLE animals ( animalId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, animalName TEXT)";
    database.execSQL(query);
    Log.d(LOGCAT,"animals Created");
  }
  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old, int current_version) {
    String query;
    query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS animals";
    database.execSQL(query);
    onCreate(database);
  }

  public void insertAnimal(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("animalName", queryValues.get("animalName"));
    database.insert("animals", null, values);
    database.close();
  }

  public int updateAnimal(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();  
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("animalName", queryValues.get("animalName"));
    return database.update("animals", values, "animalId" + " = ?", new String[] { queryValues.get("animalId") });
  }

  public void deleteAnimal(String id) {
    Log.d(LOGCAT,"delete");
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();  
    String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM  animals where animalId='"+ id +"'";
    Log.d("query",deleteQuery);   
    database.execSQL(deleteQuery);
  }

  public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllAnimals() {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
    wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM animals";
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("animalId", cursor.getString(0));
        map.put("animalName", cursor.getString(1));
        wordList.add(map);
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return wordList;
  }

  public HashMap<String, String> getAnimalInfo(String id) {
    HashMap<String, String> wordList = new HashMap<String, String>();
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM animals where animalId='"+id+"'";
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {
        wordList.put("animalName", cursor.getString(1));
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }           
    return wordList;
  } 
}
```

---

for insert data:

```
DBController controller = new DBController(myactivity.this);
HashMap<String, String> queryValues =  new  HashMap<String, String>();
queryValues.put("animalName", animalName.getText().toString());
controller.insertAnimal(queryValues);
```

[Here is sample example](http://javapapers.com/android/android-sqlite-database/)